# Using both CSS transitions and jQuery animations

Tags: jquery, css

I'm experimenting with both CSS transitions and jQuery UI functions. Before I get to my question, please check the following demos.

1. The effect that appear when you mouse over the links in [this](http://kode.co.nf/onlycss/) page is done using **only** CSS transitions.
2. In [this](http://kode.co.nf/onlyjs/) page, I've created the same effect using **only** jQuery (commented out the CSS transition rules).
3. [Here](http://kode.co.nf/both/), I've just kept both CSS and jQuery code as it is and notice there's a considerable delay in animating due to firing of both events in CSS and jQuery(*I think*).

Now my question is how can I keep them both and use one method effectively in a user's browser? For example,

- When a user opens the page and if his browser has JavaScript
  **disabled**, it runs the CSS method.
- If the user's browser doesn't support CSS transitions, it run the
  JavaScript method.

How can I achieve that?

**EDIT :** : I read about Modernizer but it won't do much good if JavaScript is disabled in the user's browser.

Comment: If you can feature-check the browser for CSS3 from Javascript, the rest should be easy (javascript sets/clears a class for the CSS to test).

Comment: Why not keep it with jQuery to make sure it works in every browser? Horray for IE7.

Comment: @OptimusCrime I'm looking for an alternative way if JS is disabled in the browser.

Comment: technically there is no way to animate on a browser that doesnt support CSS Transitions and user has javascript turned off.

Comment: @Isuru: According to http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/how-many-users-have-javascript-disabled/ that is a tiny, tiny percentage of the people who will visit your site. I think it's better to give them a warning that the site will not function correctly with js disabled.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)?

```
if(!Modernizr.csstransitions) { // Test if CSS transitions are supported
            $(function() {
                //animate
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I read about Modernizer but if JS is disabled in the user's browser, it won't work, right?

Comment: Put a class of `no-js` in the page's `body` tag. If JS is enabled in the browser, Modernizr will remove that class and add a `js` class instead. Then you know you should use CSS transitions because JS transitions won't be possible.